# Require JS config and the path for the library files

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, requirejs, r.js

Can any one explain how we can specify the path from any property inside the require JS config section.

We need to pass a property inside the config as shown below:
The problem:
var SomePathFromPropertyFile = "CDN lib path";

```
require.config({
    waitSeconds: 500,
    paths: {
        // Library js files
        'jquery': 'js/external/jquery.min',
        'angular': 'js/external/angular.min',
        'some-name': SomePathFromPropertyFile

    },

    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    }
});

define('js/common', [
    'jquery',
    'angular',
    'some-name'

], function($, angular) {
    return angular;
});
```

How can we achieve this? Currently it gives build error as SomePathFromPropertyFile is not defined.

Comment: hmm, i do that kind of stuff all the time in my require config. Could you post your entire config file?

Comment: I have added the details above....

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution to the above problem and it resolved the issue:

```
var SomePathFromPropertyFile = "CDN lib path";
define('js/common', [
'jquery',
'angular',
 SomePathFromPropertyFile
], function($, angular) {
return angular; 
});
```